# How to identify if vector iterator has reached end of vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of integers and I want my iterator to point to my desired number (call it 'test').

```
vector<int> vec;
void find(std::vector<int>::iterator iter, int test)
{
    if((*iter)!=test){ ++iter;}
}
```

That is sometimes problematic because iter might hit the end of the vector (if 'test' is not in the vector) and I'll run into an error.

Is there anyway I can perform something like

```
if(iter!=vec.end())
```

and stop the iteration without specifying my vector in the function? Thank you!

Comment: In your particular case, why don't you just use `std::find()`?

Answer (score 8):

You can take the standard library approach and pass a pair of iterators to the function:

```
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end,
         typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type test)
{
  Iterator it = begin;
  ....
  if (iterator != end) { ... }
}
```

Then you have to figure out an algorithm to find the iterator pointing to an element with value equal to `test`. Or just call `std::find` and drop your function.

```
auto it = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), test);
if (it != vec.end()) { .... }
```

Comment: He wants the iterator to point to the number (or to end()). This code (at least the first version) doesn't do what he asked

Comment: @MarcoA. How does it not do that?

Comment: If I read it correctly he wants an iterator returned somehow that points to the value asked

Comment: @MarcoA. Yes, but they are asking how to deal with getting the end iterator without the vector being passed to the function. The `....` is where the iterator to the number is found.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. I can't say from the question as it stands. Fine for me, sorry for bothering :)

Answer (score 2):

A *pair* of thoughts:

1. You're passing the iterator by value
2. Standard Library usually works by passing a begin-end couple so you can adjust your range as you wish

I'd go for something like

```
vector<int> vec;
void find(std::vector<int>::iterator& iter, std::vector<int>::iterator end, int test)
{
    while (iter != end) { 
        if (*iter == test)
            return;
        ++iter;
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> a = { 2,3,4 };
    std::vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin();
    find(it, a.end(), 5);
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e8c145708411f3)</kbd>

Anyway you could just use `std::find` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: Passing iterators by reference seems quite strange. It certainly isn't the approach taken in the standard library.

Comment: `I want my iterator to point to my desired number`. I suppose he either wants to modify his iterator or to get one in return. Still: better off with std::find.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard algo std::find, from `<algorithm>`

```
auto it = std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), value);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, vec.end() is present.
You can check this reference
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/